# How does method chaining in SwiftTask work?

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift. I want to understand how object ownership work when it comes to method chaining.

Let's use SwiftTask as an example. One of the [unit test case](https://github.com/ReactKit/SwiftTask/blob/swift/2.0/SwiftTaskTests/AlamofireTests.swift#L73) is chaining "success" and "failure" calls.

```
    task.success { (value: String?) -> Void in

        XCTFail("Should never reach here.")

    }.failure { (error: NSError?, isCancelled: Bool) -> Void in

        XCTAssertTrue(error != nil, "Should receive non-nil error.")
        expect.fulfill()

    }
```

The implementation of `success` and `failure` both return a new Task object. So, is the Task objects returned by these 2 calls retained by someone?

Please help me understand what's happening to those 2 Task objects. Thanks!

Comment: Found an post explaining simple promise implementation: https://medium.com/@robringham/promises-in-swift-66f377c3e403#.evszcrakk

Comment: As for SwiftTask implementation, the success closure is captured by the calling task: https://github.com/ReactKit/SwiftTask/blob/swift/2.0/SwiftTask/SwiftTask.swift#L449
The task object returned on calling `success` allows us to chain it to another task. (though I am not sure why a new task object instead of `self`)

Comment: You are right. And a new task needs to be created for every call of `then`-related methods. Otherwise, "first root task" must take care of all continuous tasks and that's technically a bad architecture, as already shown its defect in the comment of https://medium.com/@robringham/promises-in-swift-66f377c3e403#.d3481gwkh